# rocketmq-console taking minutes of time to showing created topics from rocketMQ client

Tags: .net, rocketmq

I have installed rocketMQ-4.1 in ubuntu server ( 18GB ram and 6 Core ), and also rocketMQ-console for dashboard.

> https://github.com/apache/rocketmq-externals/tree/master/rocketmq-console

Then i have created dotNet client for creating topics for 100,500,1000 topics in  for loop with dynamic topic name.

In broker logs and topic.json i am able to see the topics created within few seconds after firing create request from program.
But in console its taking 5-10 minutes for displaying 1000 topics.
Is there a console lag or its taking time to create topic itself and showing only topic meta in topic.json?

I also did a test with running dotnet and rocketMQ server within same host ( windows 10 laptop 16GB and 8core) its running fine and able to see topics in dashboard.

Let me know if anyone faced same issue or any suggestion for fine tuning the rocketMQ server.